# Can't Extract Users List With Roles From ASP.NET IdentityUserRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am trying to get user list with their co responding Roles. Using IdentityUser, IdentityRole, IdentityUserRole.
I have already tried different way and followed many Answer from StackOverflow.
The main issue I have, when I add Navigation property to User and Role models then in UserRole table duplicate some columns.

**Please let me know if you need more informations**

But I need your help.

Details:
User:

```
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

Role:

```
    public class Role : IdentityRole<string>
    {
        public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

UserRole:

```
    public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext:

```
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string,  IdentityUserClaim<string>,
    UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) {}

    }
```

After Migration and Updating database:
**Table** AspNetUserRoles:
[image: Snapshot of UserRole Table]

*ps: Those data inserted before.*

I getting frustrated, Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

The base type [`IdentityUserRole<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuserrole-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1) already has a `UserId` and a `RoleId`. By adding new properties for `User` and `Role`, *without* configuring the context to account for those, you are essentially introducing new properties into the table (`UserId1` and `RoleId1`) which are never populated.

You should be able to fix this by reconfiguring the context. The [default configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.6/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityDbContext.cs#L123-L140) looks like this:

```
builder.Entity<TUser>(b =>
{
    b.HasMany<TUserRole>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId).IsRequired();
});

builder.Entity<TRole>(b =>
{
    b.HasMany<TUserRole>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).IsRequired();
});
```

So if you overwrite those relationship configurations, you should be able to make your navigation properties work:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string,  IdentityUserClaim<string>, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options) {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<User>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany<UserRole>(u => u.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(ur => ur.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        builder.Entity<Role>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany<UserRole>(r => r.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

I haven’t tested this but it should replace the default configuration, so that you shouldn’t end up with duplicate columns on the `UserRole` and your navigation properties should work then.